# Centre the marker position if marker goes out of view bound android

Tags: android, google-maps

i am using google map **V2** in android, user can only view the map all other zooming spaning is set to diabled. Position of marker update after some intervals, now i want when ever the position of marker goes out of view bound the marker get centred as well as the map. so the user just see the current marker postion.

Comment: have you know about LatLngBounds.Builder ?

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder bld = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
bld.include(new LatLng(your latitude, your longitude));
LatLngBounds latLngBounds = bld.build();
yourMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
                    latLngBounds, 50));
```